# Should class-level method calls in Ruby class definitions be idempotent?

Tags: ruby, conventions

I recently ran into an issue where calling `load` twice on a Ruby class caused bugs (here's a [real-world example](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine/issues/163)). This is because there were stateful method invocations taking place in the class body, and `load` was causing these to be executed twice. A simple example is as follows:

`base.rb`:

```
class Base
  def foo
    puts "BASE"
  end
end
```

`derived.rb`:

```
require "./base"

class Derived < Base
  alias_method :foo_aliased, :foo  

  def foo
    puts "DERIVED!"
  end
end
```

Execution from a REPL:

```
$ load './derived.rb'
> true
$ Derived.new.foo
> DERIVED!
> nil
$ Derived.new.foo_aliased
> BASE
> nil
$ load './derived.rb'
> true
$ Derived.new.foo
> DERIVED!
> nil
$ Derived.new.foo_aliased
> DERIVED!
> nil
```

In this example, the second `load` causes `alias_method` to clobber the original alias. As a result, we've broken any code that depends on having an intact alias to the original method.

Brute-force class reloading is common enough (e.g., you see it a lot in the `each_run` clause for RSpec configurations using Spork) that it's not always easy to forbid the use of `load` outright. As such, it seems like the only way to prevent bugs is to ensure that class definitions are "idempotent". In other words, you have make sure that methods intended to be called from a class definition should produce the same result no matter how many times you call them. The fact that re-loads don't break more code seems to suggest an unspoken convention.

Is there some style guide for Ruby class design that mandates this? If so, what are the common techniques for enforcing these semantics? For some methods, you could just do some memoization to prevent re-execution of the same method with the same arguments, but other things like `alias_method` seem harder to work around.

Answer (score 1):

You are entirely wrong. Assuming all class methods to be idempotent is neither a sufficient nor a necessary condition for a code to not break when loaded multiple times.

Therefore, it naturally follows that there is no style guide to enforce that.

Comment: Fair enough. With the added assumption that a file only defines a module/class, do you know of any common cases that could cause a class to behave differently when loaded multiple times?

Comment: For example, suppose you have a constant defined using some random number, and do encoding of some string using that as a seed. Everytime you load it, it encodes differently, and if you try to decode it using the seed you have from the last load, you will get into trouble with the ones previously encoded.

Comment: Also fair enough, but if we expanded the idempotency requirement include all stateful expressions in the class definition (including method invocations AND assignments), does this then mean that reloading is safe?